# Go benchmark by function name

Tags: testing, go, benchmarking

I have this Benchmark function:

```
BenchmarkMyTest(b *testing.B) {
}
```

And I would like to run only this function not running all other tests, but the command never worked for me.

```
go test -bench='BenchmarkMyTest'
or
go test -run='BenchmarkMyTest'
```

What's the correct way of running one single benchmark function in Go?
It says to use regex but I can't find any documentation.

Thanks,

Comment: `go test -bench BenchmarkMyTest`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Described at [Command Go: Description of testing flags](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_testing_flags):

```
-bench regexp
    Run benchmarks matching the regular expression.
    By default, no benchmarks run. To run all benchmarks,
    use '-bench .' or '-bench=.'.

-run regexp
    Run only those tests and examples matching the regular
    expression.
```

So the syntax is that you have to separate it with a space or with the equal sign (with no apostrophe marks), and what you specify is a regexp:

```
go test -bench BenchmarkMyTest
go test -run TestMyTest
```

Or:

```
go test -bench=BenchmarkMyTest
go test -run=TestMyTest
```

**Specifying exactly 1 function**

As the specified expression is a regexp, this will also match functions whose name contains the specified name (e.g. another function whose name starts with this, for example `"BenchmarkMyTestB"`). If you only want to match `"BenchmarkMyTest"`, append the regexp word boundary `'\b'`:

```
go test -bench BenchmarkMyTest\b
go test -run TestMyTest\b
```

Note that it's enough to append it only to the end as if the function name doesn't start with `"Benchmark"`, it is not considered to be a benchmark function, and similarly if it doesn't start with `"Test"`, it is not considered to be a test function (and will not be picked up anyway).

Comment: How can we interpret the result? Say I ran ` go test -run BenchmarkPalindrome -bench=10000x` and result `ok      DSA/mathematics 0.071s`. Is `0.071` total execution time  or execution for single call?

Comment: @AnuragDhadse What is `-bench=10000x` supposed to mean? The syntax is used to tell which benchmark to run (name by regexp). What you see is no benchmark is matched by that regexp pattern, so no benchmark ran, only the "normal" tests (and they pass). `0.071s` is the time for the test run. The number of benchmark runs is determined by the benchmark framework.

Answer (score 1):

I found those answers incomplete, so here is more to the topic...

The following command runs all Benchmarks starting with `BenchmarkMyTest` (BenchmarkMyTest1, BenchmarkMyTest2, etc...) and also skip all tests with `-run=^$ .`

You can also specify a test duration with `-benchtime 5s` or you can force `b.ReportAllocs()` with `-benchmem` in order to get values like:

```
BenchmarkLogsWithBytesBufferPool-48     46416456                26.91 ns/op            0 B/op          0 allocs/op
```

---

the final command would be:

```
go test -bench=^BenchmarkMyTest . -run=^$ . -v -benchtime 5s -benchmem
```